# Комбинация клавиш в PyCharm для конвертации списка в кортеж/множество

Tags: python, pycharm

Прежде использовал, но сейчас не могу найти комбинацию клавиш, которая меняет скобки на фигурные/квадратные/круглые в зависимости от тех, которые стоят сейчас. Работает так же, как выпадающее окно у "желтой лампочки", однако куда быстрее нажать две клавиши.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно найти в `Settings` -> `Keymap` комбинацию для `Show Context Actions`.
Обычно это <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (или <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> для схемы VSCode) но могут быть и другие варианты.